# Is it possible to extrude a curve in two directions?

Tags: bezier-curves

I want to extrude a curve in two directions.

[image: curve]

Or join both curves into one, is it possible? I've tried copying it and then join segments, but I don't see *Remove Doubles* option while working with curves.

Comment: There is the Split option in the Curve menu that's available in Edit mode. I believe it just joins another curve to the current one, though.

Answer (score 14):

Not supported in Blender, curve vertex must always belong to a maximum of two segments.

Either use a mesh object with a *Skin* modifier instead, if you require true 'branching' and a continuous mesh surface.

[image: Skin modifier]

Or if you prefer curve objects duplicate a vertex in place, leave it overlapping the original one, and then extrude the new one; if you don't mind the discontinuity in the mesh.

[image: Curve branching]

You can just directly select any middle vertex and extrude it twice with <kbd>E</kbd>, the first extrude will duplicate the vertex automatically <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> to cancel and the second extrude will start a new branch.

Comment: I have posted a question maybe similar to this answer. A pop box arise before extruding and the new extruded curve is that connected to the old or we have to connected and how. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77375/how-to-make-branch-from-bezier-curve

Comment: It is not connected to the previous branch, that is not supported in Blender

Comment: To animate two curves independently read: [How to animate a bifurcated path?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135126/1853)