# how to connect two paths

Tags: modeling, path

I am trying to connect 2 separate paths somewhere along its centre, see picture:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57284/it-is-possible-to-extrude-a-curve-to-two-directions

Answer (score -1):

Select the points you want to connect and press "F".

Comment: I already tried that, it says: "cannot create segment"

Comment: Do you need to create your stuff with a curve? Otherwise convert the curve with alt-c to mesh, then press f to connect the two points and use a Skin- and Subdivisionsurface Modifier on it

Comment: I need a connecting cylinder, selecting 2 points after converting it to a mesh will simply make an edge, I can't make this edge a cylinder while remaining merged correctly with the meshes of both paths.

Answer (score -2):

If i understood your question you want to join to verts

Go to edit mode ->

Select the 2 verts and Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Alt + C will not connect two spline points. It will close the spline(s) that selected points belong to regardless of which points are selected.

Comment: Like Omar said, this doesn't work, it connect both ends, I am trying to connect a point along its centre.

Comment: @J.Point attach your file

Comment: You cannot fork a curve object, you can only float disconnected verts close to each other then make a large bevel size to hide the gap.