# 3ds max user want to find Refine and Connect tool in blender

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices, splines

Hi I'm a fellow user of spline modeling and I cant find the "refine and connect" from 3ds max in blender

this option just create a line/segment between two points/vertices of a curve/spline

so their is an option like that in blender  ? or even an add on ?

edit example of 3ds max refine and connect [image: 3dsmax refine and connect example]

edit to @gorgious i add two  screenshot
[image: bezier circle]
[image: simple circle]

Comment: Hello, typing F with 2 control points selected or going Control points > Make segment should do it. Be careful that one control point can't be connected to more than 2 other control points though.

Comment: I follow ur instruction and get this error with two different curves "bezier circle" and "simple circle "

Comment: Like I said in my second sentence, a control point can't be connected to more than 2 other control points :)

Comment: hahha okay lovely so no way to have the same option in blender like the gif show off (edit2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such tool in Blender, mainly because [curves in Blender can't branch](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57284/is-it-possible-to-extrude-a-curve-in-two-directions/57288).

One workaround is to select an vertex you wish to connect beforehand, duplicate them with <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> to cancel and leave them in place.

Then just press  <kbd>F</kbd> a bunch of times to connect them.

[image]

Beware that Blender doesn't really memorize selection sequence, the connection order will depend on the spline index the vertex was derived from, so it may not always yield expected results if the original splines were not created in the same order you want them connected.

Another potential caveat is that splines must be all of the same type (bezier, poly or NURBs), and belong to the same object, otherwise you will not be able to connect them.

Comment: This answering my Question . Too bad Blender doesn't have a real spline modeling option .... I still have to use 3ds max ... 90% of my workflow can be done in blender this is was the last part ... I really hope the next version of blender will improve this part like that I can stop using 3ds max :D

Thank you for u time !