# Bevel a curve in blender

Tags: geometry, bevel

When I bevel a curve in blender I end up with something like this[image: Curve geometry bevel]

I'd like something more like this[image]

Is there a way to achieve it ?
Thanks

Comment: Ther are no curves in either of your images. Show one with a curve in it and the settings you're using and we may be able to help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57284/is-it-possible-to-extrude-a-curve-in-two-directions/57288#57288

Comment: Curves cannot have junctions or branch off. A curve is one or multiple splines, each spline a consecutive row of segments with each control point having a maximum of 2 connections, 1 to its predecessor and 1 to its successor. The start and end point each have only one connection unless you set the spline to _Cyclic_, which automatically connects the end point with the start point. So what you see in the first image is happening because the spline with the rectangular corner is not connected to the other spline (and cannot be). Only vertices in mesh objects can have more than 2 connections.