# How to blend meshes that intertwined each other?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to make a pretzel chip but I ran into an issue where meshes are intertwined (see red circles). Below is my model (made it using Bezier Curve):

[image]

A pretzel chip has the intertwined part blended together like so:
[image]

My question is how do I blend the meshes that intertwined each other?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57288/19307

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could typically use a *Skin* modifier for this kind of object:

Draw the general shape with a simple vertex that you extrude (use a *Mirror* modifier to symmetrize, enable its *Clipping* option):

[image]

Give it a *Skin* modifier (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to scale the vertices):

[image]

Then a *Subdivision Surface* modifier in order to round the shape:

[image]

Apply the modifiers and rework the topology if you want:

[image]

Duplicate your object, give a *Subdivision Surface* to the copy, apply it in order to have a high-poly that you'll be able to sculpt:

[image]

Comment: That looks really clean! I'm going to give this a try. Thank you very much for providing a thorough answer.