join two coils together
i have this probem where i want two coils to collide, but i cant figure out a way to do it neatly

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57284/is-it-possible-to-extrude-a-curve-in-two-directions/

Did you try joining the meshes and editing the geometry? As long as they are separate meshes, you won't be able to properly connect them.
